# Get words from an array when the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array and all I want to do is when the page is fully loaded a word (inside a span tag in the html) fade out with jQuery and replaced with a word from the array, show the new word for 2 seconds and be replaced again by the next word of the array until the array is over.
It's so simply but I've tried a thousand different ways with loops and always go over the array before displaying anything on the website and when it is fully loaded shows me the last word of the array.

Here is one of my attemps:

```
$(function(){
    var words=new Array('red','blue','yellow','black','white','orange',
                        'green','brown');
    var wordList;
    for(var i in words){
        wordList=words[i];
        $("#word").fadeOut(200).html(wordList).fadeIn(200).delay(2000);
    }   
});
```

Probably the mistake is very silly but I'm starting with javascript and I'm going crazy... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `[]` instead of `new Array()`.
2. `.html` is not an animation function and will run immediately (ignoring `.delay`), so it won't go word by word. Set it only when the animation completes with the second argument you can pass to animation functions.
3. You can use `setTimeout` to run a function after a certain amount of time. The problem you'll encounter is scoping with a `for` loop (`wordList` will be the same each time). However, you can make use of `$.each` and pass a function (a function will introduce a new scope, and the scoping problem will go away).

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/EkaAF/

```
$(function(){
    var words = ['red','blue','yellow','black','white','orange', 'green','brown'];

    $.each(words, function(i, v) { // for each word (i is index, v is value)
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#word").fadeOut(200, function() { // fade out
                $(this).html(v).fadeIn(200); // when completed, set html and fade in
            });
        }, i * 2000); // 2000 * index, so each one will wait 2000 ms after previous one
    });
});
```

Comment: Nicely laid out, beat me to it =D

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb that solves everything and thanks for the tips! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would do it simply like this.

```
var wordcount = 0;
var words=new Array('red','blue','yellow','black','white','orange','green','brown');

$(window).load(function(){
    changeWord();
});

function changeWord(){
    $('#word').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $('#word').html(words[wordcount]);
        wordcount++;

        $('#word').fadeIn(200, function(){
            changeWord();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice +1, but it stays jumping at "brown". http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/EkaAF/2/ Also as a tip - you can use `$(window).load(changeWord)` as well.